# How to customize the email Template of the User Email address change Email

Tags: email, email-template, user, customization

The Users want  the content of the  notification mail which they receive on changing the Email address to be modified.
Or they want the From Email Address to be changed to a different one as some of the new users are getting confused with it.
Is it possible to achieve any one of these scenarios?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the default from email address (support@salesforce.com) can't be changed for this notification.  There's a long-standing feature request on the ideas board to allow this.  Take a look:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrsEAAS

Likewise, there's a feature request for opening up the email template for customization.  That one's over the point threshold now, but it's been about 3 years since the last update:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrGfAAK

Answer (score 0):

These are the standard Salesforce email template and unfortunately, you can't change them.

I am unable to find exact idea for email address change template, but there is similar idea you can vote.

[Customizable new-user email](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrGfAAK)